# Make a new branch the master in git without messing up existing forks

Tags: git, version-control

I have a new line of work that I want to become master.  It has diverged from master too much to merge or rebase (though I've manually ported the functionality).  I realize I can easily do a `git branch -D master; git checkout new-master; git checkout -b master`, but I don't want to screw up any forks.

Ideally, I'd like to introduce a commit that turns the current master into a state where I can apply my changes from my new branch, so that anyone with a fork can just `git pull origin master` and git things without incident.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want branch `master` to refer to a new commit whose *contents* are identical to branch `branch`, with the delta between `master^` and `master` being "change everything to match the contents of branch `branch`", that's pretty easy:

```
$ git checkout branch
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
$ git status    # you'll see what you're about to commit, here
$ git commit    # make that new commit
```

Note that the branch history for `master` will *not* refer to `branch` here.

If you want the commit to look like a merge that changes everything to the way `branch` looks, this seems to do the trick, but I have not tested it well:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --no-commit -s ours branch  # this sets up the merge
$ git rm -r .                           # this empties it out
$ git checkout branch -- .              # this adds everything from branch
$ git status   # again, just to see what you're about to commit
$ git commit   # and maybe edit the message to note that you took "branch"
```

Now `master^` is what master used to look like and `master^2` is the tip of `branch`.